# Desktop shortcut from a .sh with a delay

Tags: shortcuts, sh

I want to have a desktop shortcut for TWO apps in .sh format with a  15 seconds' delay between them during the launch. Is it possible?
What kind of script I have to do for that?
If anyone can give me an exemple please?
(Ubuntu desktop 22.04)

Thx guys!

Comment: there is a BASH/shell command `sleep` that allows you to specify how many seconds to delay; why not use it between the execution of apps?

Comment: Normally I launch the two apps with cli. But it's for launch rapidly with double click for users who doesn't know bash command..

Comment: I don't know what I have to write in the script, I never did that. Usually I copy paste existent scripts I find on internet, but I didnt find this. '

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible! In any `.sh` script, you can combine as many commands as you wish! Then use the `sleep` command to include a delay.

**1. Create a launcher script:** Thus, if you have two apps, `myapp1.sh` and `myapp2.sh`, make a third app for example `myapplauncher.sh`, with the contents

```
#!/bin/bash
myapp1.sh &
sleep 15
myapp2.sh
```

This launches the first app and forks it to the background (by adding the `&`). Thus, the script immediately proceeds with a `sleep 15` command, introducing the 15 second pause. Then the second app is launched.

**2. Create a .desktop launcher:** The next step is to make a `.desktop` shortcut for `myapplauncher.sh`.

The easiest way may be to install a tool "Alacarte" or "MenuLibre". This provides a graphical interface to create desktop launchers.

Alternatively, create a .desktop launcher yourself. It should contain at minimum:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Editor
Exec=gedit
Type=Application
```

You can add a comment (`Comment=...`), specify an icon (`Icon=...`), [and more](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/). You can see many examples of `.desktop` files under `/usr/share/applications`.

When finished creating the `.desktop` launcher, copy it into `~/.local/share/applications` if it has to appear in the menu of your user only, or into `/usr/local/share/applications` if the launcher should be available for all users. To achieve the latter, you need root permissions.